# заполнение Collection JAVA

Tags: java, коллекции

Как  написать метод,который помещает в Коллекцию сразу все объект(а не по одному)?
Есть класс Products с конструктором и переопределением toString и класс Shop который содержит коллекцию.Как правильно написать метод ,чтобы в этом случае:

```
Product product=new Product("coffe",new BigDecimal("4.63"));
    Product product1= new Product("Apple",new BigDecimal("2.27"));
    Product product2 = new Product("Kiwi",new BigDecimal("0.99"));
    Shop go=new Shop();
```

одним методом Коллекция заполнилась сразу тремя продуктами ?

остальные два класса выглядит следующим  образом:

```
public class Product {
private String name;
private BigDecimal price;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public BigDecimal getPrice() {
    return price;
}


public Product(String name,BigDecimal price){
    if (!name.isEmpty() && price!=null) {
        this.name=name;
        this.price=price;
    }
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", price=" + price ;
}

public class Shop {

private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>(10);


public void addProduct(Product product) {
    products.add(product);
}

public void removeProduct(Product product) {
    products.remove(product);
}


public List<Product> productByName(String title) {
    List<Product> product = new ArrayList<>(10);
    for (Product prod : products) {
        if (prod.getName().equals(title)) {
            product.add(prod);
        }
    }
    return product;
}

public List<Product> productInRange(BigDecimal minPrice, BigDecimal maxPrice) {
    List<Product> product = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Product prod : products) {
        if (prod.getPrice().compareTo(minPrice) > 0 && prod.getPrice().compareTo(maxPrice) < 0) {
            product.add(prod);
        }
    }
    return product;
}


public void addAllProducts() {

}
```

Comment: А какой принцип выбора определенных продуктов, т.е. допустим,покупатель выбирает определенные продукты через CheckBox или как ? Просто в зависимости от реализации выбора, можно проще написать алгоритм добавления товаров.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void addProducts(Product... products) {
    Collections.addAll(this.products, products);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

должен подойти вариант с varargs.

http://www.linkex.ru/java/varargs.php

```html
public void addProduct(Product... product) {
for(Product p : product)
products.add(p);
}
```

А в основном -

```html
go.addProduct(product,product1,product2);
```

Однако хотелось бы еще узнать саму реализацию подачи товара, думаю можно сделать лучше.

Answer (score 0):

Уберите инициализацию `ArrayList` и создайте конструктор таким образом

```
public Shop(Product ... products){
   this.products = Arrays.asList(products);
}
```

потом через него можно будет заполнить список таким образом:

```
Product product=new Product("coffe",new BigDecimal("4.63"));
Product product1= new Product("Apple",new BigDecimal("2.27"));
Product product2 = new Product("Kiwi",new BigDecimal("0.99"));
Shop go=new Shop(product,product1,product2);
```